# Controller that only exist 2-controls, pitch bend and modulation

Tags: midi, digital-piano, midi-controller-keyboard

Right now I use my digital piano(yamaha p-35) and a midi-controller behringer umx.

I Paired them together so that I can use my behringer functions alongside with my digital piano.
But there was a thing bothered me that Pairing those things is not too easier to use and not flexible, in case I just need controls of pitch bend and modulation only, since my digital doesn't have that controls.

So.. Is there a midi-controller without keyboard tuts, and has only two controls(pitch-bend and modulation)?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly, technically, do you mean with "paired"? And what do you think would that controller do different than the UMX? Is your problem just that the UMX's keys make it too big?

Comment: basically I connect my yamaha digital piano with a midi-usb cable to my pc. So that when I work together with my yamaha and umx, my pc detect 2 midi-device(yamaha(using midi port) and umx), and then I called it "paired" because I can use umx function alongside with my yamaha. Yes you are right. umx keys is to big since I have yamaha 88 keys, so umx tuts are useless. I still using umx because I want to use its function(control) since my yamaha does'nt have a control like pitch bend and modulation. It's becomes very flexible if I found a midi controller that just exist 2control(picth&modulation)

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic, so I'm not allowed to tell you about devices like the nanoKontrol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few immediate options:

- [Make one yourself](http://forum.moogmusic.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=12909)
- Buy parts for another keyboard and rewire (Some keyboards have modular wheel sections that can be removed.
- Trade in/up your controller for one with what you need on it :)

Other than that, this will be hard to find because *almost every* controller and keyboard sold comes with this on board, and those that do not don't have it because most people have more of these than they need on other gear.  It is rare that someone is lacking one.